# Is it possible to use values from application.properties to set field of Hibernate @Table annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-el

I have a Spring, Hibernate application. I would like to set `scheme` property of `@Table` annotation like this using value from `application.properties` file.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "${hibernate.scheme}")
public class Holidays { 
   // code
}
```

But it does not work. Spring does not substitute `${hibernate.scheme}` with property value. Is there a way to solve it?

I am trying to do this to use different scheme for tests.

Comment: No. Annotations need to be static . Next to that placeholders is a Spring functionality and not Hibernate.

Comment: You can set schema in `application.properties` using `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=schema`

Answer (score 1):

You can try default_schema: ${schema} in your app.yml and in test, you can supply the value of schema in app-test.yml.